# Java: Updated variable in one class will not update in another

Tags: java, swing

I am working with GUI in Java. I am trying to create a program for an imaginary restaurant, and it includes 2 classes.

1. A restaurant menu
2. Display of totals

## Restaurant menu

Layout:

1. Menu items: on the left
2. The selected item, that you select to order: on the right

There are 2 buttons in the middle that the user will click on if they want to select an item for their order, or remove it from their order.

## Display of totals

The other class displays the subtotal, tax, and adds a couple of choices for gratuity, and finally will display total.

## Interaction

For the class with the menu, I have a total variable that is initialized to 0.

If the user wants to add an item to his order, he needs to click a specific button. Then it will update the total price.

I am making this variable `static` so that the class that shows the total can interact with it.

## Problem

The problem that I am having is that **this variable does not seem to update** in the class that shows the total. It still shows that the total variable is 0, even though that I am directly calling it from the other class.

If anyone has any thoughts or any tips that can help me, please do so, because I am seriously stuck on this. Thank you

*P.S. These classes are part of another class that will create objects of these classes, so these classes do not have a public static void main() method*

This is my class that shows the restaurant menu.

```
import java.awt.event.*;   
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MenuFrame extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

final double BURGER_PRICE = 6.24;
final double FISH_PRICE = 13.78;
final double SOUP_PRICE = 4.49;
final double CHICKEN_PRICE = 11.36;
final double SALAD_PRICE = 5.60;
final double FRIES_PRICE = 3.24;
JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel();                       //Panel to place the menu in, which will be on left side
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();                     //Panel to place buttons in, which will be in center
JPanel orderPanel = new JPanel();                      //Panel to place order menu in, which will be on right side
JLabel menuLabel = new JLabel("Menu");                 //Label for the menu
JLabel orderLabel = new JLabel("Your Order");          //Label for the user's order
JCheckBox burger = new JCheckBox("Burger: $6.24", false);     //Burger check box
JCheckBox fish = new JCheckBox("Fish: $13.78", false);         //Fish check box
JCheckBox soup = new JCheckBox("Soup: $4.49", false);         //Soup check box
JCheckBox chicken = new JCheckBox("Chicken: $11.36", false);   //Chicken check box
JCheckBox salad = new JCheckBox("Salad: $5.60", false);       //Salad check box
JCheckBox fries = new JCheckBox("Fries: $3.24", false);       //Fries check box
JButton rightButton = new JButton("->");               //Button to move items from left to right
JButton leftButton = new JButton("<-");                //Button to move items from right to left
static double totalPrice = 0;                                        //Total price of order
Font titleFont = new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,20);


public MenuFrame() {
    
    setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));                    //Setting this panel's layout to GridLayout
    setSize(1055, 275);                                //Set size of Menu Frame
    
    menuPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));         //Setting menuPanel layout to GridLayout
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,3));       //Setting buttonPanel layout to GridLayout
    orderPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));        //Setting orderPanel layout to GridLayout
    
    menuLabel.setFont(titleFont);                     //Setting font's of menuLabel and orderLabel to titleFont
    orderLabel.setFont(titleFont);
    
    //Adding menu items to Menu                       //Adding menu items to menuPanel, along with adding new JLabel's to skip positions
    menuPanel.add(new JLabel(""));                    //in GridLayout
    menuPanel.add(menuLabel);
    menuPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    menuPanel.add(burger);
    menuPanel.add(fish);
    menuPanel.add(soup);
    menuPanel.add(chicken);
    menuPanel.add(salad);
    menuPanel.add(fries);
    
    //Adding "Your Order" label to orderPanel. Items will be subsequently added or removed. Also adding new JLabel's to skip positions
    orderPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    orderPanel.add(orderLabel);
    orderPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    
    //Adding new JLabels, rightButton, and leftButton so that the buttons will be placed on top of each other
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(rightButton);
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(leftButton);
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    
    
    //Adding action listener to rightButton and leftButton
    rightButton.addActionListener(this);
    leftButton.addActionListener(this);
    
    //Adding menuPanel, buttonPanel, and orderPanel to MenuFrame
    add(menuPanel);
    add(buttonPanel);
    add(orderPanel);
    
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    Object source = e.getSource();
    
    //If right button was clicked
    if(source == rightButton) {
        
        //if burger was selected and is in the menu panel
        if(burger.isSelected() && burger.getParent() == menuPanel) {
            
            //Move burger from menu to order, deselect burger, and add 6.24 to total price
            menuPanel.remove(burger);
            orderPanel.add(burger);
            burger.setSelected(false);
            totalPrice += BURGER_PRICE;
            
        }
        
        //if fish was selected and is in the menu panel
        if(fish.isSelected() && fish.getParent() == menuPanel) {
            
            //Move fish from menu to order, deselect fish, and add 13.78 to total price
            menuPanel.remove(fish);
            orderPanel.add(fish);
            fish.setSelected(false);
            totalPrice += FISH_PRICE;
            
        }
        
        //if soup was selected and is in the menu panel
        if(soup.isSelected() && soup.getParent() == menuPanel) {
            
            //Move soup from menu to order, deselect soup, and add 4.49 to total price
            menuPanel.remove(soup);
            orderPanel.add(soup);
            soup.setSelected(false);
            totalPrice += SOUP_PRICE;
            
        }
        
        //if chicken was selected and is in the menu panel
        if(chicken.isSelected() && chicken.getParent() == menuPanel) {
            
            //Move chicken from menu to order, deselect chicken, and add 11.36 to total price
            menuPanel.remove(chicken);
            orderPanel.add(chicken);
            chicken.setSelected(false);
            totalPrice += CHICKEN_PRICE;
            
        }
        
        //if salad was selected and is in the menu panel
        if(salad.isSelected() && salad.getParent() == menuPanel) {
            
            //Move salad from menu to order, deselect salad, and add 5.60 to total price
            menuPanel.remove(salad);
            orderPanel.add(salad);
            salad.setSelected(false);
            totalPrice += SALAD_PRICE;
            
        }
        
        //if fries was selected and is in the menu panel
        if(fries.isSelected() && fries.getParent() == menuPanel) {
            
            //Move fries from menu to order, deselect fries, and add 3.24 to total price
            menuPanel.remove(fries);
            orderPanel.add(fries);
            fries.setSelected(false);
            totalPrice += FRIES_PRICE;
            
        }
        
    }
    
    //if left button was clicked
    if(source == leftButton) {
        
        //if burger was selected and is in the order panel
        if(burger.isSelected() && burger.getParent() == orderPanel) {
            
            //Move burger from order to menu, deselect burger, and remove 6.24 from total price
            orderPanel.remove(burger);
            menuPanel.add(burger);
            burger.setSelected(false);
            totalPrice -= BURGER_PRICE;
            
        }
        
        //if fish was selected and is in the order panel
        if(fish.isSelected() && fish.getParent() == orderPanel) {
            
            //Move fish from order to menu, deselect fish, and remove 13.78 from total price
            orderPanel.remove(fish);
            menuPanel.add(fish);
            fish.setSelected(false);
            totalPrice -= FISH_PRICE;
            
        }
        
        //if soup was selected and is in the order panel
        if(soup.isSelected() && soup.getParent() == orderPanel) {
            
            //Move soup from order to menu, deselect soup, and remove 4.49 from total price
            orderPanel.remove(soup);
            menuPanel.add(soup);
            soup.setSelected(false);
            totalPrice -= SOUP_PRICE;
            
        }
        
        //if chicken was selected and is in the order panel
        if(chicken.isSelected() && chicken.getParent() == orderPanel) {
            
            //Move chicken from order to menu, deselect chicken, and remove 11.35 from total price
            orderPanel.remove(chicken);
            menuPanel.add(chicken);
            chicken.setSelected(false);
            totalPrice -= CHICKEN_PRICE;
            
        }
        
        //if salad was selected and is in the order panel
        if(salad.isSelected() && salad.getParent() == orderPanel) {
            
            //Move salad from order to menu, deselect salad, and remove 5.60 from total price
            orderPanel.remove(salad);
            menuPanel.add(salad);
            salad.setSelected(false);
            totalPrice -= SALAD_PRICE;
            
        }
        
        //if fries was selected and is in the order panel
        if(fries.isSelected() && fries.getParent() == orderPanel) {
            
            //Move fries from order to menu, deselect fries, and remove 3.24 from total price
            orderPanel.remove(fries);
            menuPanel.add(fries);
            fries.setSelected(false);
            totalPrice -= FRIES_PRICE;
            
        }
        
    }
    
    //Make changes appear
    repaint();            
    revalidate();        
    
}
```

This class is the class that shows the total and tax

```
package finalproject;

import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TaxAndGratuityFrame extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    final double TAX_RATE = 0.07;               //Tax rate 
    JLabel subtotal = new JLabel("Subtotal");    //Sub-total label
    JLabel tax = new JLabel("Tax");              //Tax label
    JLabel gratuity = new JLabel("Gratuity");    //Gratuity label
    JLabel total = new JLabel("Total");          //Total label
    JLabel other = new JLabel("Other        $");          //Other label for user entered gratuity
    JTextField subtotalTextField = new JTextField(10);    //Displays sub-total
    JTextField taxTextField = new JTextField(10);         //Displays 8% tax
    JTextField otherGratuity = new JTextField(10);        //Allows user to enter gratuity
    JTextField totalTextField = new JTextField(10);       //Displays total
    JButton enterOtherGratuity = new JButton("Enter");  //Applies gratuity to total
    JButton nextPage = new JButton("Next Page");        //Displays next page when entered
    JCheckBox zeroPercent = new JCheckBox("0%", false);         //0% gratuity
    JCheckBox fifteenPercent = new JCheckBox("15%", false);    //15% gratuity
    JCheckBox twentyPercent = new JCheckBox("20%", false);     //20% gratuity
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    double subtotalVariable;                //Variable used for the subtotal
    double taxVariable;                     //Variable used for tax
    double finalTotal;                      //Variable for the total bill
    double gratuityVariable;                //Variable for gratuity
    Font otherFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 15);
    
    
    
    public TaxAndGratuityFrame() {
        
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0,7));
        setSize(470,375);
        
        //Adding check boxes to button group so that only one can be selected
        group.add(zeroPercent);
        group.add(fifteenPercent);
        group.add(twentyPercent);
        
        //Setting subtotal, tax, and total text fields to disabled so that user's cannot change value
        subtotalTextField.setEditable(false);
        taxTextField.setEditable(false);
        totalTextField.setEditable(false);
        
        //Initializing subtotal variable and tax variable
        subtotalVariable = MenuFrame.totalPrice;                 //Using totalPrice variable from MenuFrame
        taxVariable = subtotalVariable * TAX_RATE;
        
        //Displaying subtotal and tax in their respective JLabels
        subtotalTextField.setText("$" + subtotalVariable);
        taxTextField.setText("$" + taxVariable);
        
        //Adding action listener to 'other gratuity' button and 'next page' button and checkboxes
        enterOtherGratuity.addActionListener(this);
        nextPage.addActionListener(this);
        zeroPercent.addActionListener(this);
        fifteenPercent.addActionListener(this);
        twentyPercent.addActionListener(this);
        
        //Setting fonts for labels
        subtotal.setFont(otherFont);
        tax.setFont(otherFont);
        gratuity.setFont(otherFont);
        total.setFont(otherFont);
       
        
        //Adding components along with new JLabels so that components are in the correct position
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(subtotal);
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(subtotalTextField);
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(tax);
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(taxTextField);
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(gratuity);
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(zeroPercent);
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(fifteenPercent);
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(twentyPercent);
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(other);
        add(otherGratuity);
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(enterOtherGratuity);
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(total);
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(totalTextField);
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        Object source = e.getSource();
        
        //if user clicked enter button
        if(source == enterOtherGratuity) {
            
            //Uncheck the check boxes if any are selected
            group.clearSelection();
            
            //Store what user entered into 'gratuityVariable', and add this variable, subtotalvariable, and tax variable
            //to get final
            gratuityVariable = Double.parseDouble(otherGratuity.getText());
            finalTotal = gratuityVariable + subtotalVariable + taxVariable;
            
            totalTextField.setText("$" + finalTotal);
            
        }
        
        if(source == zeroPercent) {
            
            //If there is anything typed in the other gratuity text field, clear it
            otherGratuity.setText("");
            
            //If not gratuity, just add subtotal and tax
            finalTotal = subtotalVariable + taxVariable;
            
            totalTextField.setText("$" + finalTotal);
            
        }
        
        if(source == fifteenPercent) {
            
            //If there is anything typed in the other gratuity text field, clear it
            otherGratuity.setText("");
            
            //Calculate fifteen percent gratuity and add that to subtotal and tax to get final
            gratuityVariable = ((subtotalVariable + taxVariable) * 0.15);
            finalTotal = gratuityVariable + subtotalVariable + taxVariable;
            
            totalTextField.setText("$" + finalTotal);
            
        }
        
        if(source == twentyPercent) {
            
            //If there is anything typed in the other gratuity text field, clear it
            otherGratuity.setText("");
            
            //Calculate twenty percent gratuity and add that to subtotal and tax to get final
            gratuityVariable = ((subtotalVariable + taxVariable) * 0.2);
            finalTotal = gratuityVariable + subtotalVariable + taxVariable;
            
            totalTextField.setText("$" + finalTotal);
            
        }
        
        //Makes changes appear
        repaint();
        revalidate();
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: There is too much code to look at.  You say "I have a total variable that is initialized to 0.  ... The problem that I am having is that this variable does not seem to update in the class that shows the total."  I assume this variable has a name?  And so does the class?  It would be nice to clue us in to what the name is, so that we don't have to look at 500 lines of code and guess what you're referring to.

Comment: But I do have one comment: if you update a variable in a class (or an instance variable in an object), that will change the data inside the computer, _but that will not automatically change any data displayed on the screen_.  You have to take some action to tell Swing to display the right value.  Since I'm not very proficient in Swing and this is a ton of code to look at, I can't tell just what needs to change.  Some Swing components have methods to set a value that will cause the display to change, but you need to call them after changing the variable.

Comment: When you create a GUI, you need to create a GUI model and separate the data from the GUI view.  1) Create an Item class that has the name of the item and the price.  2) Create a GUI model class that holds a List of Item objects, the customer order, and the total value.  3) Create the GUI view to use the Menu object to create the JList selection.  4) Your JButton action listeners will update the fields in the GUI model and validate the GUI view.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. I appreciate it

Comment: You really shouldn't create questions with these huge walls of text. I just took a hammer and broke it in many pieces. As you can see, it's more inviting to read a question which is structured.